# Clojure mutable storage types

Tags: multithreading, clojure, future, mutable

I'm attempting to learn Clojure from the API and documentation available on the site. I'm a bit unclear about mutable storage in Clojure and I want to make sure my understanding is correct. Please let me know if there are any ideas that I've gotten wrong.

Edit: I'm updating this as I receive comments on its correctness.

---

**Disclaimer: All of this information is informal and potentially wrong. Do not use this post for gaining an understanding of how Clojure works.**

---

**Vars** always contain a root binding and possibly a per-thread binding. They are comparable to regular variables in imperative languages and are not suited for sharing information between threads. *(thanks Arthur Ulfeldt)*

**Refs** are locations shared between threads that support atomic transactions that can change the state of any number of refs in a single transaction. Transactions are committed upon exiting sync expressions (dosync) and conflicts are resolved automatically with STM magic (rollbacks, queues, waits, etc.)

**Agents** are locations that enable information to be asynchronously shared between threads with minimal overhead by dispatching independent action functions to change the agent's state. Agents are returned immediately and are therefore non-blocking, although an agent's value isn't set until a dispatched function has completed.

**Atoms** are locations that can be synchronously shared between threads. They support safe manipulation between different threads.

Here's my friendly summary based on when to use these structures:

- Vars are like regular old variables in imperative languages. (avoid when possible)
- Atoms are like Vars but with thread-sharing safety that allows for immediate reading and safe setting. *(thanks Martin)*
- An Agent is like an Atom but rather than blocking it spawns a new thread to calculate its value, only blocks if in the middle of changing a value, and can let other threads know that it's finished assigning.
- Refs are shared locations that lock themselves in transactions. Instead of making the programmer decide what happens during race conditions for every piece of locked code, we just start up a transaction and let Clojure handle all the lock conditions between the refs in that transaction.

Also, a related concept is the function `future`. To me, it seems like a future object can be described as a synchronous Agent where the value can't be accessed at all until the calculation is completed. It can also be described as a non-blocking Atom. Are these accurate conceptions of future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are really getting Clojure! good job :)

Vars have a "root binding" visible in all threads and each individual thread can change the value it sees with out affecting the other threads. If my understanding is correct a var cannot exist in just one thread with out a root binding that is visible to all and it cant be "rebound" until it has been defined with (def ... ) the first time.

Refs are committed at the end of the (dosync ... ) transaction that encloses the changes but only when the transaction was able to finish in a consistent state.

Comment: You explain these corrections very clearly, thanks! The root binding idea confuses me a bit because I don't see any advantage for it. I assume it's for more of a technical reason like keeping mutable variables off the stack so they don't get deallocated.

Answer (score 4):

I think your conclusion about Atoms is wrong:

> Atoms are like Vars but with thread-sharing safety that blocks until the value has changed

Atoms are changed with `swap!` or low-level with `compare-and-set!`. This never blocks anything. `swap!` works like a transaction with just one ref:

1. the old value is taken from the atom and stored thread-local
2. the function is applied to the old value to generate a new value
3. if this succeeds compare-and-set is called with old and new value; only if the value of the atom has not been changed by any other thread (still equals old value), the new value is written, otherwise the operation restarts at (1) until is succeeds eventually.

Comment: Ah, I think you're right, there's no blocking. In that case, I wonder what it means when they say that Atoms are synchronous.

Comment: swaps aren't quite like transactions in that they don't compose with other transactions - be careful if you use swap! within a transaction as it isn't transaction-safe, in particular it might get retried multiple times or interfere with another running transaction.

Answer (score 3):

I've found two issues with your question.

You say:

> If an agent is accessed while an action is occurring then the value isn't returned until the action has finished

http://clojure.org/agents says:

> the state of an Agent is always immediately available for reading by any thread

I.e. you never have to wait to get the value of an agent (I assume the value changed by an action is proxied and changed atomically).

The code for the `deref`-method of an `Agent` looks like this (SVN revision 1382):

```
public Object deref() throws Exception{
    if(errors != null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Agent has errors", (Exception) RT.first(errors));
    }
return state;
```

}

No blocking is involved.

Also, I don't understand what you mean (in your Ref section) by

> Transactions are committed on calls to deref

Transactions are committed when all actions of the dosync block have been completed, no exceptions have been thrown and nothing has caused the transaction to be retried. I think `deref` has nothing to do with it, but maybe I misunderstand your point.

Comment: Hi pmf, I feel you're confused about Agents. An Agent's *state* is always immediately available but its value is changed asynchronously by Clojure when the action function completes after you call send. In my explanation I was only referring to the last step of Agent dispatching, as follows: "5. If during the function execution any other dispatches are made (directly or indirectly), they will be held until after the state of the Agent has been changed." That's the only blocking occurring here.

Comment: My statement about committing transactions is from memory based on slides I read from Rich Hickley, although I'm probably wrong. To me it also makes more sense to commit after dosync.

Answer (score 1):

Martin is right when he say that Atoms operation restarts at 1. until is succeeds eventually.
It is also called spin waiting.
While it is note really blocking on a lock the thread that did the operation is blocked until the operation succeeds so it is a blocking operation and not an asynchronously operation.

Also about Futures, Clojure 1.1 has added abstractions for promises and futures.
A promise is a synchronization construct that can be used to deliver a value from one thread to another. Until the value has been delivered, any attempt to dereference the promise will block.

```
(def a-promise (promise))
(deliver a-promise :fred)
```

Futures represent asynchronous computations. They are a way to get code to run in another thread, and obtain the result.

```
(def f (future (some-sexp)))
(deref f) ; blocks the thread that derefs f until value is available
```

Answer (score 0):

Vars don't always have a root binding. It's legal to create a var without a binding using

```
(def x)
```

or

```
(declare x)
```

Attempting to evaluate x before it has a value will result in

```
Var user/x is unbound.
[Thrown class java.lang.IllegalStateException]
```